# java creating arraylist an abstract method that increments and stores the increment

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract-class

I need a little bit of help.
I'm doing an assignment for college at the moment and I have hit a stumbling block on a small part of the problem.

Let me give you the background. 
Lecturer totally useless. 
Reads from book. 
Has done no worked examples.
Robbed assignment from another lecturer.

Now the problem that I have, is that she has given us an abstract method to implement as follows

```
    public abstract int getId();
```

This is to marry with the usual stuff of first name, last name, gender....... which will go into an arraylist. This I can do in my sleep.

The problem is that I can cover for the functionality when I'm building the code by using a String and I can successfully build the rest of the assignment other than this part.
It would be easier if she had left as a string as there is no mathematical computations being done.
I cannot leave it as a string though as it is requirement which would get 50% deducted.

Thanks for any help in advance guys.

Keith

Comment: I can see a lot of sentences about how bad your lecturer is. But you forgot to mention: 1. what's your requirement, 2. What is the problem that you're facing and 3. what have you tried

Comment: Thasnks for getting back to me. What I'm currently building is a program that simultes a creche management system. The parent and the child has an unique id number that if you remove a record then the record is removed but if you add another parent or child then they will use the incremented id number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats wrong with:

```
public class YourClass extends YourAbstractClass {

    private static int id = 0;

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return ++id;
    }

}
```